# Remove >> in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This function: `(fprintf(append("wellSols2",num2str(i-2))))`   is supposed to give wellSols22 when i=4. But it gives `wellSols22>>`. How do I ensure that only wellSols22 comes out, so without the >>   ?

Thank you

Comment: The ">>" is the MATLAB command prompt. Try running this: `fprintf(append("wellSols2",num2str(i-2))); pause`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the "new line" `"\n"` character. Try something like:

```matlab
fprintf( strcat(append("wellSols2",num2str(i-2)),'\n') )
```

or even better this

```matlab
fprintf("wellSols2%i\n", i-2 )
```

if i is an integer (specified by `%i`). Other types can be specified if you like [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf8xsy-1_sep_shared-formatSpec).

---

After your comment, if your data `wellSols` and `states` are different types/sizes, then an alternative to dynamic variable naming might be to put them in a structure, which could look something like this:

```matlab
x = 6; y = 20; % some input variables for your function
ii = 4;     
[storage_structure(ii).wellSols, storage_structure(ii).states] = simulateScheduleAD(x,y);

% Main function
function [A, B] = simulateScheduleAD(x, y)

% some output variables which have different types / sizes
A = rand(x,y);
B = "mystring";

end
```

Comment: Hi teeeeee, I have the following:  [fprintf("wellSols2%i\n", i ), fprintf("states2%i\n", i )] = simulateScheduleAD(state, model, schedule2);  this means that wellsols22 and states22 (if i=2) are the output matricies. However I get the following error: Unable to use a value of type string as an
index.

Error in Schedulingusingloops02082021 (line
128)
[fprintf("wellSols2%i\n", i ),
fprintf("states2%i\n", i )] =
simulateScheduleAD(state, model, schedule2);

Comment: @SulAt this is because you are trying to use dynamic variable names, and trying to create a variable in the workspace on the fly. It can be fixed by using ```eval()```, e.g. we can make a variable states22 = 6 by using ```eval( [sprintf('states2%i', i ) ' = 6'] )```. HOWEVER! Whenever you end up doing this, there is almost always a better way to do it. I am not sure exactly what the output of your function simulateScheduleAD() looks like (2D matrices?), but it is better to store your data in some other form. E.g you could have it in a structure such as states2(i) = 6.

Comment: @SulAt See here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval

Comment: @SulAt This is also helpful https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Comment: @SulAt I have given an example in the answer.